# Block js pushed by server on webpagetest

Tags: webpagetest

I do some test blocking a js file to see the impact of it on the perf. I have a case where the js file is directly pushed by the server.
How can I block this js ?

Comment: What do you mean by "directly pushed by the server": an inlined JavaScript inside HTML output? or http/2 push feature? (I assume the first)

Comment: I mean an http/2 server push. Looks like the file is flagged as downloaded but not executed, hard to know what is the behavior. For normal download the file is clearly flagged as not downloaded.